# how to check if a value is present in all selected rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables :

table : names

```
name_id  name   
 1       jack    
 2       jill
```

table : pets

```
name_id    animal   status
1          dog       Y
1          cat       N
2          dog       Y
2          cat       Y
```

how should i write query to return rows from table : names which have status 'y' for all mapped rows in table : pets?

that is , i need a query that will return `jill`

Comment: what your expected output please mention here

Answer (score 3):

You can do so, get the count of all rows (for each name) which has a status of Y  and this count must be equal to the count of all associated records for each name

```
select n.* from name n
join pets p  on(n.name_id = p.name_id)
group by n.name_id
having sum(p.`status` = 'Y') = count(*)
```

`sum(p.status = 'Y')` will give the count of rows with status Y per
   name

`count(*)` will give the count for all associated rows per name

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66dfb/4)

Comment: How can I use count(*) when my query also joins other tables? Will it work the same way?

Comment: @mercy You need to show your other tables how you are using them in query for the provided 2 tables the above should work as expected but for other tables i am not sure

Comment: When you join more tables, the `count(*)` and the `sum()` could return different values. There could be duplications (based on the other joined tables), or if one of the joined tables filters out some pet records, you could get false positive results. Definetily, it will be better if we could see all of your tables and your goal!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach you can use:

```
SELECT
  * -- Don't forget to list the columns you want to retrieve. Avoid using SELECT * !
FROM
  names N
WHERE
  -- This will *include* all names who has at least one pet with status 'Y'
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pets P WHERE N.name_id = P.name_id AND P.status = 'Y')
  -- This will *exclude* all names who has at least one pet with status 'N'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pets P WHERE N.name_id = P.name_id AND P.status = 'N')
```

Check the [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0978f2/1)

*M Khalid Junaid*'s approach is a good one too so do not forget to check his answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using @mkhalidjunaid's fiddle...

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.* 
  FROM name n
  JOIN pets x
    ON x.name_id = n.name_id
  LEFT
  JOIN pets y 
    ON y.name_id = x.name_id
   AND y.status = 'n'
 WHERE y.status IS NULL
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66dfb/13

Comment: This will list all names including those which has no pet record!

Comment: It won't list 'all' names - but I see what you mean. See edit.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't precise enough